# Javascript React sessionstorage if loggedIn change Nav links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sessionstorage

I have a sessionstorage variable which is called loggedIn.

If it's set to true (user is logged in) I need to change the login link to :

```
<li><a href="" onClick('logout()')>Logout</li>
```

so I can use the logout method to change the sessionStorage variale to false.

Here is the current code:

```
class Nav extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.isLoggedIn = sessionStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn') === 'true';
    this.state = {
      message: 'You are Logged In',
    };

}

logout() {
  sessionStorage.setItem('loggedIn', false);
  // then update changes
}

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</li>
        <li><a href="#login">Login</li> // If Not logged in change this to <li><a href="" onClick('logout()')>Logout</li>
        <li></li> // If loggedin the show Message here
      </ul>
    )
  }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Maintain the user login status by the `state` variable, store the `isLoggedIn` variable in `state` and update that variable on the basis of user login status.

Use [conditional rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to `render` different elements on the basis on `isLoggedIn` value.

Another change is the way you defined the click event on logout, it should be:

```
onClick={this.logout}
```

And bind this method in the `constructor`.

Check the doc: [How to handle events in JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html)

Write it like this:

```
class Nav extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        message: 'You are Logged In',
        isLoggedIn: sessionStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn') === 'true'
      };
      this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
  }

  logout() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('loggedIn', false);

    //here update the state variable

    this.setState({
      isLoggedIn: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</li>

        {/*use condition here if user is loggedin then render the logout otherwise login button*/}          

        {this.state.isLoggedIn ? 
            <li><a href="" onClick={this.logout}>Logout</li>
          :
            <li><a href="#login">Login</li> 
        }

        <li></li>
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator in jsx like this:

```
{this.isLoggedIn ? <li><a href="" onClick={this.logout}>Logout</a></li> : <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>}
```

and if you want to some messge if a condition is true, then you can do it like this:

```
{this.isLoggedIn && <li>Your message</li>}
```

It would be better if you store isLoggedIn in state.

For more detail, just go here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html